# How do i do the equals method in this program? Are the resize and clone methods correct?

Tags: java

Here were the requirements:

Adding to `IntList`:

- `resize` method: Write a resize method for IntList that doubles the size of the array. As discussed 
  in chapter 7, you cannot simply resize an array, you must instantiate a new array with increased 
  size, copy everything from the old array to the new array, then assign the old array reference to 
  the new array. For this application, the resize method will ONLY be used by the subclass, but it is 
  good functionality for the IntList class to have.
- `equals` method: Write an equals method for IntList. Remember to use the Object parameter! 
  Two IntList objects should be considered equal if they have the same number of elements 
  (without regard to capacity) and each element in each index matches in value.
- `clone` method: Write a clone method for IntList. Remember that the clone method should not 
  have parameters, and should return an Object. Your clone method needs to make a deep copy so 
  that the returned object doesn’t contain any aliasing.

(I just need help with the `equals`, and i would appreciate if you could check if my `clone` and `resize` work as intended)

```
public class IntList
{

    private int[] list;
    private int numElements;

    /**
    * Constructor -- creates an integer list of a given size.
    * @param size the number of elements in the list
    */
    public IntList(int size)
    {
        list = new int[size];
        numElements = 0;
    }

    /**
    * Adds an integer to the list.  If the list is full,
    * prints a message and does nothing.
    * @param value the value to add
    */
    public void add(int value)
    {
        if (numElements == list.length)
            System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
        else
        {
            list[numElements] = value;
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Retrieves the integer at a specified index
    * @param index the index to retrieve
    * @return the integer at that index
    */
    public int getNum(int index)
    {
        return list[index];
    }

    /**
    * Sets the integer at a specified index
    * @param index the index to change
    * @param num the number to assign at index
    */
    public void setNum(int index, int num)
    {
        list[index] = num;
    }

    /**
    * returns the number of elements in the list
    * @return number of elements
    */
    public int getNumElements()
    {
        return numElements;
    }

    /**
    * returns the length (capacity) of the list
    * @return length
    */
    public int getLength()
    {
        return list.length;
    }

    /**
    * Returns a string containing the elements of the list with their
    * indices.
    * @return the String version of the IntList
    */
    public String toString()
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
            returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
        return returnString;
    }

    // Add resize, equals and clone, and their javadocs
    public void rezise()
    {
        int [] temp = new int[list.length*2];
        for(int i = 0; i<numElements; i++)
        {
            temp[i]=list[i];
            setNum(i,getNum(i));
        }

    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        IntList a = (IntList)o;
        if(a.numElements != numElements)
        return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            list[i]!=a.list[i];

        }

    }

    public Object clone()
    {
        IntList a = new IntList(numElements);
        for(int i = 0; i<numElements; i++)
        {
            a.add(list[i]);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: its really long cuz of the javadocs srry...i only need help on 3 methods

Comment: What's your question? What is your point of confusion? What help do you need? All I see are requirements and a code dump. Please try to put just a little effort into asking your question.

Comment: Your code as is doesn't even compile... you know, if you can compile it your can run it and see if it does what you want.

Comment: i dont know how the equals method works...its supposed to be eqauls if all the values are the same....but how do i do this with out calling any gat... methods

Comment: the equals doesnt compile, cuz i dont know how to do it...

Comment: You have presumably read your text on it and some tutorials -- please clarify just what you don't understand from what you've read. Don't simply dump your assignment here for us. A good rule of thumb is to try to put as much effort into asking your question as you'd like someone to apply answering it.

Comment: i really need help on this...its only a single method that im confused on....i would apreciate some help

Comment: okay the thing is, how to I get the equals method to check if each value is the same at each index without calling a get---- method

Comment: cuz my teacher said it was gauche to call getters in a class

Comment: You have direct access to the fields, so you can get the fields directly from the variables, from the `this` object and from the parameter object.

Comment: @user3331208 Your teacher is doing you a disservice by being an idiot; but if you do want to avoid getters (for some reason) you can just access the fields directly; e.g. `System.out.println(getNumElements())` or `System.out.println(numElements)` -- same thing in your case.

Comment: You don't need a IntList you can use a built-in list called ArrayList to store Integers.. without any problem! like this `List<Integer> IntList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: i know, my teacher told me that, but do : return this.list[i]= a.list[a]

Comment: First check that o is an `instanceof` the type of your class. Next, you're already accessing your fields. Return false if any of the key fields don't match.

Comment: i really dont understand how the booleans work, since i cannot return in the loop because that only checks the first value

Comment: so i have to access the values of this and the values of a

Comment: instead of  `list[i]!=a.list[i];` use `if(list[i]!=a.list[i])`

Comment: how do i check each one within the for loop

Comment: if(list[i]!=a.list[i])
     return false;
else
    return true?

Comment: Look above ^ that checks if(value i in list (doesn't equal) value i in list a)

Comment: wow, you cant rally tye code in the comments

Comment: You can't `return true` cuz that will only equal the first value in the list not all of them....... Only `return true` once you checked them all.. I would set a boolean to true.. then set it to false when one of them doesn't match.. if it isn't true at the end.. then you had atleast 1 or more that didn't match up. You could return false on first non-match to stop checking the rest of them.. but you can't  return true when only checking one value.

Comment: oh i tried that, except my teacher said it was gauche....

Comment: she tends to complicate things a lot because of this

Comment: so like this:{
  intlist temp = ((IntList)o)
  if(numElements == (temp.numElements)
  {
   for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
   {
    if(list[i] != temp[i])
    {
     return false
    }
   }
   return true;  
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: dang, you cant really read that sorry; is there anyway to type code?

Comment: You have to start using http://www.pastebin.com and pasting links

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem, and does not provide an SSCCE.

Comment: @user3331208 If you want to type short bits of inline code in a comment, `type \`backticks\` around the code`. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Yes you could use ``` (tilda/tilde keys) (right under the ESC Key)

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use getters or not (your teacher's claim is dubious) is somewhat irrelevant to how `equals` must work. First, think what `equals` means in general: It returns `true` if this `IntList` is equal to another specified `IntList`.

Ok, so now what does it mean for two `IntList`s to be equal? Well, like your description says:

1. They must have the same number of elements.
2. Their element lists must be identical (for every index `n`, `this.list[n]` must equal `o.list[n]`.

Those are pretty straightforward rules. In general once you have these kinds of rules laid out, it should become easier to translate them from English to Java.

You can either access the fields directly (e.g. `o.numElements`) or via getters (e.g. `o.getNumElements()`), whether you do that or not mildly affects your syntax but generally has no effect on your logic.

In many cases (although certainly not all) you would want to use getters if your class is not `final`, because derived classes may have different implementations, and you'd want to use those implementations instead of direct field access which may bypass them.

Comment: Sometimes, if you find yourself confused during the implementation, it helps to think about what makes two objects *not* equal instead; e.g. if *any* items in the list do not match, then the objects are definitely not equal.

Comment: @SSpoke Thank you. Your teaching method is commendable and effective.